# Removing phrase from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
(function() {

    function takeRecordingAway() {
        try {
            let $title = document.querySelector('.progTitle');
            let splitInfo = $title.textContent.split(' ');
            let lastInd = splitInfo.lastIndexOf('Recording');
            let filterResult = splitInfo.slice(lastInd, splitInfo.length).join('');
            let finalResult = splitInfo.join('').replace(filterResult, '');
            $title.textContent = finalResult;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Error", e);
        }
        
    }
    
    function init() {
        takeRecordingAway();
    }
    init();
})();
```

```html
<div class="progTitle">Advisory Round: Key Steps for StartupsRecording is not available for this program</div>
```

I am trying to remove a phrase from a string. The phrase I want to remove is 'Recording is not available for this program' from this string:

'Advisory Round: Key Steps for StartupsRecording is not available for this program'

How would I be able to find this phrase and remove it?

Currently I am using this function that is not exactly working:

```
(function() {

function takeRecordingAway() {
    try {
        let $title = document.querySelector('.progTitle'); //div containing the phrase
        let splitInfo = $title.textContent.split(' ');
        let lastInd = splitInfo.lastIndexOf('Recording');
        let filterResult = splitInfo.slice(lastInd, splitInfo.length).join('');
        let finalResult = splitInfo.join('').replace(filterResult, '');
        $title.textContent = finalResult;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error", e);
    }
    
}

function init() {
    takeRecordingAway();
}
init();
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the `textContent` of the title with a filtered `textContent` value using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) would do the trick.

```js
function removePhraseFromTitle(phraseToFind) {
  const title = document.querySelector('.progTitle');
  title.textContent = title.textContent.replace(phraseToFind, '');
}

removePhraseFromTitle('Recording is not available for this program');
```

```html
<div class="progTitle">Advisory Round: Key Steps for StartupsRecording is not available for this program</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression that captures the said phrase in this scenario. Then use `String.prototype.replace()` to remove it.

```
function removePhrase(str) {
    const re = /(Recording is not available for this program)/g;
    return re.replace(re, '');
}
```